# Datatype dropdown in XAML designer not showing custom Class

Tags: c#, treeview, prism, hierarchicaldatatemplate, xaml-designer

I have a TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate that I'm trying to bind with an ObservableCollection of custom types.
But the HierarchicalDataTemplate's `DataType` attribute's dropdown list of available types in my Namespace is incomplete, it's missing the `TFolderItem` custom type, but listing all the other custom types in that same namespace. The namespace is `MyProject.Classes`, and classes are in plain Classes folder in the project directory.
I don't understand why it's not showing in the XAML code editor dropdown.

```
public class TFolderItem
{
    /*public FolderItem(RemoteDirectoryInfo rdi, WinSCP.Session winscpSession)
    {
        RDI = rdi;
        this.WinSCPSession = winscpSession;
    }*/

    public TFolderItem(string path, WinSCP.Session winscpSession)
    {
        RDI = winscpSession.ListDirectory(path);
        this.FtpPath = path;
        this.WinSCPSession = winscpSession;
    }

    private WinSCP.Session winscpSession;

    public RemoteDirectoryInfo RDI { get; set; }

    public string FtpPath { get; set; }

    public WinSCP.Session WinSCPSession
    {
        get { return this.winscpSession; }
        set { this.winscpSession = value; }
    }

    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            var children = new CompositeCollection();

            var subDirItems = new List<TFolderItem>();
            var subDirFiles = new List<RemoteFileInfo>();

            foreach (RemoteFileInfo rfi in RDI.Files)
            {
                if (rfi.IsDirectory)
                {
                    subDirItems.Add(new TFolderItem(this.FtpPath + rfi.Name + "/", this.WinSCPSession));
                }
                else
                {
                    subDirFiles.Add(rfi);
                }
            }

            children.Add(new CollectionContainer
            {
                Collection = subDirItems
            });
            children.Add(new CollectionContainer
            {
                Collection = subDirFiles
            });

            return Children;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the view's xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject2.Views.FTPTab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject2.Views"             
         xmlns:MyProject2Classes="clr-namespace:MyProject2.Classes"                 


         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding FolderItems}" Height="300" Width="300">
        <TreeView.Resources >
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="" ItemsSource="{Binding Childrenx}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FtpPathr}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType=":">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

This is the viewmodel:

```
public class FTPTabViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public FTPTabViewModel(string host, WinSCP.Session winscpSession)
    {
        this.Host = host;
        this.FolderItems = new ObservableCollection<TFolderItem>();
        this.Session = winscpSession;            

        this.FolderItems.Add(new TFolderItem("/",Session));
    }

    private WinSCP.Session session;
    private ObservableCollection<TFolderItem> folderItems;
    private string host;

    public string Host
    {
        get { return this.host; }
        set { this.host = value; }
    }

    public WinSCP.Session Session
    {
        get { return session; }
        set { this.session = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TFolderItem> FolderItems
    {
        get { return folderItems; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this.folderItems, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to fix your code if you neither show your XAML, nor the code behing / view model?

Comment: First of all, your bindings are incorrect. You have `FtpPathr` instead of `FtpPath` and `Childrenx` instead of `Children`. That the TFolderItem class is missing might simply be due to the fact that you haven't compiled your code since you added that class.

Comment: Bindings are incorrect because I was trying to get any sort of Bindings debug in output console.<br/>I've tried clean and rebuild solution, but it didn't help.

Comment: It seems that if I remove the constructor from TFolderItem, the x:type dropdown shows the TFolderItem as available type. Can anyone tell me why is that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that x:type dropdown only displays classes with default constructor.
Adding one in TFolderItem class made it display in x:type dropdown.